# Putting html inside PHP

Tags: php, html

So I was wondering if its possbile to put a html code inside PHP code

I have this nice login page for html but I'm using PHP to help store the username and password.

I want use that login page I have for html with the PHP code I'm using.

I tried searching and people said use echo but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Any help is appreciated.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
   require('config.php');

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $user = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']);
     $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

     $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($check) >= 1){
     echo "Success";
     exit();
   }
  else{

  echo "Wrong password";
  }
 }
 else{
  <<<<add html code here>>>
   }
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="Home.html" method="POST">
<div class="container">
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user" required>

<label><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>

<button type="submit">Login</button>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please add the code you're trying to get working to the body of your question. Although learning is nothing to be ashamed of, Stack Overflow has a pretty strict focus on questions pertaining to code you've written, not code you intend to write, or on advice how to write code. If you've **tried something**, that's the most important thing here.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: You can change the extension of an .html file to .php and then use php in that file with the tag <?php      [some code]    ?>

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro I tried to copy and paste the html and it worked but for some reason it lets me login even if the password is wrong, before I had a plain login made from php and it worked. Any help?

Comment: @tadman I added code I've written

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to display the form again on that last else statement? if so just do:

```
<?php
   require('config.php');

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $user = mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']);
     $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

     $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
     if(mysql_num_rows($check) >= 1){
     echo "Success";
     exit();
   }
  else{

  echo "Wrong password";
  }
 }
 else{
?>
  <form action="Home.html" method="POST">
  <div class="container">
  <label><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user" required>

  <label><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>

  <button type="submit">Login</button>

  </div>

  </form> 
<?php
   }
?>
```

While this is definetely not the **Correct** way of doing it, it will do what you want. There are several better ways of doing it which you will learn later on.

Sidenote: I hope this script that you are running is not for a live app/website but for some homework you have where security is not an issue. If this is for a live website then you might aswell not use any login/register script as that can be soooo easily bypassed. just google php secure login and you will find some good examples. Passwords need to be encrypted on the database otherwise they will be compromised. Also try and google PHP form validation, it will give you some insight on what is going on with that sql injection you are vulnerable to. Here's a good link to start: http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input-Validation.html

Comment: for some reason, I can still type in anything and it will allow me to go to home.html even if the user name and password isn't correct.

Comment: That's because of  'form action="home.html'. No matter what you put in the form, it will still redirect you to home.html

Comment: how would I make it so that it goes to home.html, would I need a if statement of some sort.

Comment: Remove the form action="home.html". Where you have 'echo "success"' replace "success" with the html code that you have inside home.html in the same way I did with the form. Again, and I can't stress this enough, this will solve your homework exercise, but it's not something that you want in a live page.

Comment: thanks and thank for the precaution, its not for a live page, its for a project I'm doing but it wont be used by anyone but me and the marker.

Comment: Tell your marker to explain you how the $_SESSION variable works. Ideally, where you have echo 'success';, you will set something like $_SESSION['status'] = 'user'. Then whenever you want do display the content for users you will do if(isset($_SESSION['status'])& $_SESSION['status']=='user'){--user html in here--}

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?  if($guest) { ?>
    Show Login Form HTML <?  } ?>



    <?  if($user) { ?>
    Hide Login Form HTML <?  } ?>
```

just a small hint, i use something like this, check if variables exist to show or hide html, there may be much beter ways to do this.